# Printing issue in Python

Tags: python, list, printing, shuffle

I feel like an idiot for even asking this but does anyone have any idea why my code is printing the list after every shuffle?

```
def shuffle(L, nswaps):
    n = 0
    for item in L:
        while n < nswaps:
            card_one = choose(L)
            card_two = choose(L)
            if card_two == card_one:
                card_two = choose(L)
            n += 1
            L[card_one], L[card_two] = L[card_two], L[card_one]
        print L
```

NB I haven't pasted the import/ calling the function stuff as it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Maybe you want to dedent the `print` statement by one level?

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't work, but now it is *head-desk*. Thanks very much. :)
If you wanted to copy that into an answer I can give you the points (I'm assuming the points system is like in Y!A)

Comment: It's refreshing to see a forum where people don't point-whore. Thanks regardless of whether you got the points anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with your indents:

```
def shuffle(L, nswaps):
    n = 0

    for item in L:
        while n < nswaps:
            card_one = choose(L)
            card_two = choose(L)

            if card_two == card_one:
                card_two = choose(L)

            n += 1
            L[card_one], L[card_two] = L[card_two], L[card_one]

        print L
```

Notice that the `print L` statement is in the same level as the contents of the `for` loop (which is why it is called each time you loop).

Delete four spaces from the whitespace preceding the `print L` and all should go well.

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement is inside the for loop, so it's going to print L for each element in L.

Try un-indenting it to the same level as the for loop, to put it outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement is inside the for, so It'll be executed once for each element in the list :).

Try doing something like this:

```
def shuffle(L, nswaps):
    n = 0
    for item in L:
        while n < nswaps:
            card_one = choose(L)
            card_two = choose(L)
            if card_two == card_one:
                card_two = choose(L)
            n += 1
            L[card_one], L[card_two] = L[card_two], L[card_one]
    print L
```